# Two PHP tables side by side

Tags: php, html-table, alignment, center

I am new to PHP; please help me.

I am trying to align two PHP tables with images in them side by side but they are displaying one below the other. I want two tables side by side under one heading and two tables side by side under second heading. I've seen some solutions in HTML but I am looking for PHP. Please find screenshot of my error and my code below:

Please feel free to ask for any clarifications.

```
$prodcatSQL="select prodcatid, prodcatname, prodcatimage from prodcat"; // create an $sql variable and store the sql statement

$exeprodcatSQL=mysql_query($prodcatSQL) or die (mysql_error());

while ($arrayprod=mysql_fetch_array($exeprodcatSQL))


{

    echo "<strong>Using display: inline-block; </strong><br>\n"; 
    echo "<table border=1 class=\"inlineTable\">\n"; 
    echo "<tr>\n"; 
    echo "<td><p><a href=products.php?u_prodcatid=".$arrayprod['prodcatid'].">";
    echo $arrayprod['prodcatname'];
    echo "<p><img src=images/".$arrayprod['prodcatimage']."></p>";
    echo "</a></p></td>\n";
    echo "</tr>\n";
    echo "</table>\n";
}


echo "<h3><center>".$subheading."</center></h3>"; 

$treatcatSQL="select treatcatid, treatcatname, treatcatimage from treatcat"; // create an $sql variable and store the sql statement

$exetreatcatSQL=mysql_query($treatcatSQL) or die (mysql_error());

while ($arrayprod=mysql_fetch_array($exetreatcatSQL))


{


    echo "<strong>Using display: inline-block; </strong><br>\n"; 
    echo "<table border=1 class=\"inlineTable\">\n"; 
    echo "<tr>\n"; 
    echo "<td><p><a href=treatmentpackages.php?u_treatcatid=".$arrayprod['treatcatid'].">";
    echo $arrayprod['treatcatname'];
    echo "<p><img src=images/".$arrayprod['treatcatimage']."></p>";
    echo "</a></p></td>\n";
    echo "</tr>\n";
    echo "</table>\n";
}
```

Comment: I am trying to add screen shot of the error message and copy of CSS but as I am new so not allowed. I can e-mail if required. Many thanks

Comment: `"I've seen some solutions in HTML but I am looking for PHP."` - You do realize that this PHP code emits HTML, right?  And that the alignment and styling is something that happens client-side in the HTML/CSS, right?  If you *have seen* solutions, in what way did those solutions not work for you?

Comment: Probably the easiest way would be to have PHP echo a table around your existing code ... <table><tr><td>stuff from first</td><td>stuff from second</td></tr></table>

Comment: you're not aligning "PHP tables". PHP has no tables. You're trying to align some HTML... PHP may be generating the HTML, but it's up to **YOU** to generate the proper html.

Comment: can you update your question to add screenshot  ?

Comment: Consider using a template system if you are struggling using html, so you can focus on the html without thinking of php.

Comment: Hi david, I don't want to use HTML in my PHP page hence converted that HTML code into PHP in my code above. is it possible I can send you my screen shot and CSS. Thanks

Comment: Hi John, can you pls edit my code according to your recommendation.

Comment: @peterB: `"I don't want to use HTML"` - Then I have some bad news for you... You're using HTML everywhere in that code.  All of those `<table>` and `<strong>` and `<p>` tags, basically anything in those strings that's between `<>` characters, is HTML.  And all of the styling is done client-side in HTML and CSS.  If you're going to be writing web pages, you might want to make the occasional use of HTML.

Comment: What's the css for inlineTable ?

Comment: #inlineTable 
{
display: inline-block;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have nested `<p>` tags which may be introducing unnecessary new lines. Remove the

tags and replace them with separate `<td>` elements and the alignment should be fine.
    $prodcatSQL="select prodcatid, prodcatname, prodcatimage from prodcat"; // create an $sql variable and store the sql statement

```
$exeprodcatSQL=mysql_query($prodcatSQL) or die (mysql_error());

while ($arrayprod=mysql_fetch_array($exeprodcatSQL))


{
    echo "<strong>Using display: inline-block; </strong><br>\n"; 
    echo "<table border=1 class=\"inlineTable\">\n"; 
    echo "<tr>\n"; 
    echo "<td><a href=products.php?u_prodcatid=".$arrayprod['prodcatid'].">";
    echo $arrayprod['prodcatname'];
    echo "</a></td><td><a href=products.php?u_prodcatid=".$arrayprod['prodcatid']."><img src=images/".$arrayprod['prodcatimage'].">";
    echo "</td></a>\n";
    echo "</tr>\n";
    echo "</table>\n";
}
$treatcatSQL="select treatcatid, treatcatname, treatcatimage from treatcat"; // create an $sql variable and store the sql statement

$exetreatcatSQL=mysql_query($treatcatSQL) or die (mysql_error());

while ($arrayprod=mysql_fetch_array($exetreatcatSQL))


{


    echo "<strong>Using display: inline-block; </strong><br>\n"; 
    echo "<table border=1 class=\"inlineTable\">\n"; 
    echo "<tr>\n"; 
    echo "<td><a href=treatmentpackages.php?u_treatcatid=".$arrayprod['treatcatid'].">";
    echo $arrayprod['treatcatname'];
    echo "</a></td><td><a href=treatmentpackages.php?u_treatcatid=".$arrayprod['treatcatid'].">";
    echo "<img src=images/".$arrayprod['treatcatimage']."></a>";
    echo "</td>\n";
    echo "</tr>\n";
    echo "</table>\n";
}
```

If this does not work, please edit the HTML output into the question.

Comment: actually i didn't see the rest of your code. man what a mess. try `mysql_num_rows()` on both mysql results to see if they have the same number of rows.. IE `<?php if(mysql_num_rows($exeprodcatSQL) != mysql_num_rows($exetreatcatSQL)) die("houston we have a problem"); ?>`

Comment: sorry boss I am new to this so tend to take longer route, pls can you suggest any simpler way to do the same thing

Comment: Add this: `<?php if(mysql_num_rows($exeprodcatSQL) != mysql_num_rows($exetreatcatSQL)) die("<script>alert('houston we have a problem')</script>"); ?>`

to the bottom of your code. then report back and tell us if there was an alert. if not you have to fix your html.

Comment: Thanks XaxD, tried it again. 4 tables all coming one below another not side by side

Comment: this my CSS  #inlineTable 
{
display: inline-block;
}

Comment: put them all in a <div> together.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to your table, if you don't want external CSS

Replace this in each,

```
echo "<table border=1 class=\"inlineTable\">\n";
```

With this

```
echo "<table border=1 class=\"inlineTable\" style=\"width:50%;float:left;\">\n";
```

Comment: You need to escape the double quotes EDITED

Comment: almost working vector but the tables are not aligned and images in them are not displaying

Comment: Try reducing the percentage down to 40% (just for testing) as you could have margin and padding causing an issue. If the images are not displaying it is probable due to their size being reduced and causing them to break. It may be worth moving the styling to an external sheet or at the very least the `<head>` of the document. Your image needs a styling added. inline would be `<img src=images/".$arrayprod['treatcatimage']." style=\"max-width:100%;\" />` don't forget the closing tag.

Comment: Tried 40% didn't work. Vector can i pls e-mail u my css and error screen shot? thanks

Comment: system is not allowing me to chat or attach screenshot

Comment: try `width:10%` =) Tables must be aligned side by side

Comment: have you got a link to the site?

Comment: No vector, its on my local machine. I am using EasyPHP module. I can e-mail you the page and CSS, if that is ok with you

Comment: I think may be something wrong with CSS. How can I upload, system is not allowing me to do so